# Show $(a-1)\mid a^{n+1} -a(a-1)n -a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The hint states :
 $a^{n+1} -a(a-1)n -a$ 
$= (a-1)(a^n+a^{n-1}+\ldots+a -n) $
$ =(a-1)((a^n-1)+(a^{n-1}-1)+\ldots+(a-1))$
$=(a-1)^2(a^{n-1}+2a^{n-2}+\ldots+n)$

But, I am confused at each step, particularly the first step in the division of powers of $a$, due to taking common factor as $(a-1)$. Similarly, in the last step, unable to divide to get second common factor again as $(a-1)$. Can I be guided at each step.

---

*Edit* Based on answers and comments, have progressed till: 
I have computed incompletely, as follows:
 $a^{n+1} -a(a-1)n -a = a((a^n-1) - (a-1)n) $ $= (a-1)(a(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} + a^{n-3}+\ldots+a+1) -n)$ $=(a-1)((a^{n} + a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}+\ldots+a^2+a) -n)$.

For the last step, have to take another factor of $(a-1)$ again.

Taking cue from the earlier factorization, $(a-1)^2[{(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} + a^{n-3}+\ldots+a+1)} + {(a^{n-2} + a^{n-3}+\ldots+a+1)} +{(a^{n-3} + a^{n-4} + a^{n-3}+\ldots+a+1)}+{(a^{n-4} + a^{n-5} + a^{n-6}+\ldots+a+1)}+\ldots+{a+1}+{1}]$.

So, each term apart from the first & last, i.e. $a^{n-1}, 1$ appears more than once with coefficients same as in Pascal's triangle(combinatorial expansion).
Also, there are $n-1$ terms' expansion apart from the last term $1$, so there are $(n-1)$ times extra occurrences of $1$, totaling to $(n-1)+1=n$..

Hence, proved.

Comment: Note that the claim is equivalent to $a-1|a^n-1$

Comment: @Peter Not clear, please elaborate.

Comment: $a(a-1)n$ is clearly divisible by $a-1$ and since $a$ and $a-1$ are coprime, you can factor out the $a$ in the remaining expression as well.

Comment: An even more elegant way is to apply $a\equiv 1\mod (a-1)$ which easily shows the congruence $a^{n+1}-a(a-1)n-a\equiv 0\mod (a-1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p(x)$  be the polynomial:

$p(x):=x^{n+1} + -x(x-1)n -x$ ,$ n \in \mathbb{Z^+}.$

$p(1) = 0$, hence

$p(x) = q(x)(x-1)$, where $q(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.

Hence $(x-1)$ divides $p(x).$

Comment: Can there be no way to prove $(a-1)$ as factor that would show the steps too. I mean that the quotient finding is not clear.

Comment: It does not help with your algebra steps, but to prove divisibility -as stated in the header - it may qualify.

Comment: Jiten.If you are still stuck, let me know , I shall try to help out on the algebra a little later, ok?

Comment: Please see the edit, and suggest more.

Comment: Seems that you are doing fine in your edit to extract another factor (a-1).Would not know what to add to your solution.Except that you persevered and got the answer.+

Answer (score 2):

$$a^{n+1}-a(a-1)n-a=a(a^n-(a-1)n-1)=a(a^n-1)-a(a-1)n$$

The whole expression is divisible by $(a-1)$ if and only if $(a^n-1)$ is divisible by $(a-1)$.

Comment: It is a hint, I suppose, which can be elaborated only till: $a^{n+1} -a(a-1)n -a = a((a^n-1)-(a-1)n)$. Please expand in detail.

Comment: I hope your idea is used by me in the edit of the OP.